# The extension Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 requires administrative privileges in order to be uninstalled

Tags: visual-studio

I am getting this error while trying to update Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: error msg is very clear and explicit....

Answer (score 1):

From the start menu, type "Visual Studio" and **right** click its icon.
Click run as administrator and then proceed to run update.
This should resolve the problem.